# How to create an html file with a value from dataframe column as a filename for each dataframe row?

Tags: html, pandas

I have a csv file with `ID` column. I would like to know if it would be possible to get each ID value from my dataframe and save it as a separate html file with ID value as a filename and ID assigned as a variable in that html file.

my.csv

```
ID    Name
1     ACME
2     EMCA
#and so on...
```

Desired output in local directory:

```
/path/to/my/1.html
/path/to/my/2.html
```

each html file should have declared ID variable and html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
var ID="1";
document.title = ID;
</script>   
</head>
<body>
#I want to pass ID as a text and class in my html file
<div class='1'>My First 1</div> 

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("/path/to/my.csv", quotechar='"')
for i in data['ID']:
    id_filename = str(i)
    data.to_html('/path/to/my/'+id_filename+'.html')
```

How can I write HTML code to the HTML files that are being saved with the ID values in their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
data = pd.read_csv("/path/to/my.csv", quotechar='"')

for ID in in data['ID']:
    toWrite = f"""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>
    var ID="{ID}";
    document.title = ID;
    </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
    #I want to pass ID as a text and class in my html file
    <div class='{ID}'>My First {ID}</div> 

    <p>My first paragraph.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
     """
    
    with open(f'/path/to/my/{ID}.html', "w") as file:
        file.write(toWrite)
```